# Setting a variable after promise has finished

Tags: javascript

I have something that looks like this:

```
let x = "";

     $("#container").croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'original',
        format: 'jpeg'
    }).then(function (response) {
        x = response;
    });

console.log(x);
```

x always returns `Promise Pending`. I know a promise is an async process, but is there a way I can make the variable equal to the response?

Comment: No you can't reason you already mentioned its async.

Comment: why are you not returning promise object and access that promise object there

Comment: @SourabhSomani How would you access the promise object?

Comment: that will be accessible in **then** only